# spring mongodb embedded set in document

Tags: spring, mongodb, entity

I am using spring roo with mongodb.  I would like to create an entity that contains an embedded set of a user-defined type such that it is in the same mongodb document as the other fields in the entity.  I naively thought that I could just put @Embedded on my set but this does not work.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use any annotation, simply define the Set user-defined types as a member of the class being stored:

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooMongoEntity
class Entity {
  String field1;
  String field2;
  Set<SubEntity> embeddedEntites;
}

@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
class SubEntity {
  String fieldA;
  String fieldB;
}
```

Comment: You're right.  My issue stemmed from the fact that the tests that were automatically generated were not assigning values to my subentities so I did not see the columns in mongodb.

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense.